# The default value isn't getting selected in the picklist

Tags: picklist, record-type, cpq, default-value, orderitem

I have a picklist field named Reporting type in the Quote Line Item object, for which I have set the default value as "Performance Reporting" at the field level.

And also, there are no report types for this object. And yet, the default value isn't getting automatically selected during the new record creation. Can anyone please let me know why this is happening?

I am attaching the screenshots of the same for your reference. Thanks in advance.

**Selected Default value**

[image: default value set]

**Default Value not getting selected in picklist**

[image]

**Zero Record types in the Quote line object**

[image]

Comment: I think in this situation, you actually need the same field on the product option and set the defaults there.

Comment: @DanielHoechst That worked! can you please add this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are configuring products, the fields actually need to be on the product option object with the defaults set there. Make sure you make the field type and api names match to the fields on the quote line.